# Lotties change to random colors In DarkMode

Tags: android, kotlin, lottie

The lotties change to random colors when I use DarkMode on my mobile.
How can I get the normal colors?
In the simulator the colors on blackmode are okay but in my mobile change.

Comment: What's a "lottie"? Are you actually creating a dark theme, or are you relying on your device to make an automatic, fake "dark mode"? Have you tried asking at https://es.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The android:forceDarkAllowed property is used to control whether an application allows force dark to be applied to UI components that do not support dark mode. Setting this property to false indicates that you do not want this feature to be applied in your application. use it in the theme of your app.

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

Example:

```
SetApplicationAttribute(android:theme, "@style/Custom")
CreateResource(values-v20, theme.xml,
<resources>
  <style
  name="Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
     <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
     <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

[original source here](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/disabling-system-darkmode-in-your-app.127411/#content)